# Using javascript to set an HTML class name

Tags: javascript, html, css, class

Is it possible to put a javascript function call in place of a HTML class name so that the class can be set based upon the results of the function? For example, something like:

```
<a class="fSetClass(vName)" ....
```

which would call a function named fSetClass() and receive back a valid CSS class name based upon the parameter vName passed with it.

Thanks

Comment: And that class name would be set once in the initialization of the page? Then PHP/C#/...

Comment: No, but you can use JavaScript to change the classname of an element, (though you can't do something like `class="fSetClass()"` and expect it to work. This is more of the PHP realm really, not JavaScript.

Comment: do you mean like addClass() or removeClass() functions of jquery?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to do what you're asking from within the HTML. Though, you can use JavaScript to add the class to it afterward.

Answer (score 1):

Smth like this, if in short way
    
    `document.onload = function(){

        document.getElementById('your-element-id').className = fSetClass(vname);

    }`

Answer (score 0):

No but what you can do is use jquery to get the item and then add or remove class names from it:

HTML

```
<div class="my-class">My Content</div>
```

jQuery

```
// will produce <div class="my-class added-class">My Content</div>

var addClass = 1;

if(addClass == 1) {
    $(".my-class").addClass("added-class");
}
else
{
    $(".my-class").removeClass("removed-class");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only the `on*` event handler attributes are evaluated as JavaScript code, the other attributes are not.

As already said, you have to assign the class normally with JavaScript. Assuming you have a reference to the element (`element`), you have to assign the class to the [`className` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.className) property:

```
element.className = fSetClass(vname);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use jquery, you can set the class by using .attr():

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function fSetClass(vName){
     $("#element_id").attr('class', vName);
  }

  fSetClass('className');

});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use jQuery, you can use the addClass function

```
$(element).addClass('add-this-class');
```

If you want to set the class instead, use attr:

```
$(element).attr('class','add-this-class');
```

Comment: And what if he is not using jQuery?

Comment: adding a class != setting a class